# Element-wise minimum of two numpy arrays indexed by another array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ndarray

I have three arrays of shapes:

```
A = a = np.random.exponential(1, [10, 1000000])  # of shape (10, 1000000)
B = a = np.random.exponential(1, [10, 1000000])  # of shape (10, 1000000)
```

I computed another array IND[ ] as below. Each element of IND[ ] is index of the maximum element of A (maximum of each 10 values in a column) ,

```
IND = np.argmax(snr_sr, axis=0)  # of shape (1000000,)
```

I want to calculate another array C, which contains the element-wise minimum values of A and B at row# specified by values of IND[ ]. Thus the C array should be of the shape (1, 1000000). I want to avoid for loops. I tried the below, but the values of C are not correct.

```
for j in range(0, A.shape[1]):    
        m  = ind[j]
        C  = minimum(A[m,:], B[m,:])  # return 1x1000000 array
```

> Sorry, as the arrays are large, could not post it. You can take any
>   arrays of the same shapes.
>
> **First Edit:**
>   Somebody provided me with the right answer, but he deleted it (don't know why?)
>   Anyhow, I copied the answer before he deleted it. Please post it again so that I can mark it correct. (To him: Who took arrays of 1,100 for simplicity).

Comment: you found argmax but not argmin?

Comment: First compute the minimum of A and B row-wise and store it in an array; then index that array using `ind`.

Comment: Can you provide 2 arrays of 5 elements and show us what you need as expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shortened your arrays:

```
a = np.random.exponential(1, [10, 100])  # of shape (10, 100)
b = np.random.exponential(1, [10, 100])
ind=np.argmax(a,axis=0)
```

Use that `ind` to select one row per column in `a` and `b`:

```
a_ = a[ind,np.arange(a.shape[1])]
b_ = b[ind,np.arange(a.shape[1])]
```

And then calculate `c`:

```
c=np.minimum(a_, b_)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's beautifully solved. What if the "ind" is a random selection on axis=0 instead of maximum??

Comment: It should be the same, if `ind` >9 it will throw an indexing error though

Comment: No, I mean if I want the index of randomly selected elements of the two arrays instead of ind = np.argmax(a, axis=0), just for example, ind=np.argrandom(a, axis=0)  (np.argrandom doe not exist, I am just curious if such a function exist?)

Comment: Calculate random `ind`? Use the `random` module: `ind=np.random.randint(0,10,a.shape[0])`

Comment: I think it works. Let me verify it by seeing the final results. Thank you so much Brenlla. You were really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: I am not proficient in numpy, so there might be more efficient solutions.**

First find the minimum of values in A and B row-wise:

```
minAB = np.min(np.minimum(A, B), axis=1)
```

Then index this array using `ind`:

```
C = minAB[ind]
```